# how to read a select statement into a c# datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm making an asp.net website which it shows a datatable from an excel file uploaded

i want to comparise the name from the excel columnns "Ciudad" and "ClienteProveedr" with the tables with the same name(these tables come from a sql server database), so i want to show the id from both data tables in the datatable region.

this is a sample code what i'm making of.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && Upload.HasFile)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(Upload.FileName).Equals(".xlsx"))
            {
                var excel = new ExcelPackage(Upload.FileContent);
                var Facturas = excel.ToDataTable();

                //fix ClienteProveedor 
                Facturas.Columns.Add("Proveedor", typeof(Int32));
                Facturas.Columns.Add("MasivoFacturacion_Solicitantes", typeof(Int32));
                Facturas.Columns.Add("MasivoFacturacion_Empresa", typeof(Int32));
                Facturas.Columns.Add("MasivoFacturacion_EmpresaMensajeria", typeof(Int32));
                Facturas.Columns.Add("idCiudad", typeof(Int32));
                Facturas.Columns.Add("MasivoFacturacion_ClienteProveedor", typeof(Int32));
                foreach (DataRow rw in Facturas.Rows)
                {
                    rw["Proveedor"] = Responsable.SelectedIndex;
                    rw["MasivoFacturacion_Solicitantes"] = DropDownListSolicitantes.SelectedIndex + 1;
                    rw["MasivoFacturacion_Empresa"] = DropDownListEmpresa.SelectedIndex + 1;
                    rw["MasivoFacturacion_EmpresaMensajeria"] = DropDownListEmpresaMensajeria.SelectedIndex + 1;
                    rw["MasivoFacturacion_ClienteProveedor"] = /*row for IdClienteProveedor*/;
                    rw["MasivoFacturacion_ClienteProveedor"] = /*row for IdCIudad*/;
                }
                gvData.DataSource = Facturas;
                gvData.DataBind();
                ViewState["dtFacturas"] = Facturas;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does excel.ToDataTable return? Is it actually a DataTable? If so you don't need to manually add columns and loop through the rows. Just set the DataSource and bind it.

Comment: Yeah, the excel.ToDataTable method imports the data from an exce file into a data table

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataTable ReadExcelFile(string sheetName, string path)
{

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string Import_FileName = path;
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
{
    comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]";

    comm.Connection = conn;

    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
        da.SelectCommand = comm;
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

}
}
```

You can use the above code for reading the excel into Data table and from the data table you can get the required columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method returns a DataTable you can make this a lot simpler. Something like this should be pretty close to what you need.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && Upload.HasFile)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(Upload.FileName).Equals(".xlsx"))
            {
                DataTable Facturas = new ExcelPackage(Upload.FileContent).ToDataTable();
                gvData.DataSource = Facturas;
                gvData.DataBind();
                ViewState["dtFacturas"] = Facturas;
            }
        }
    }
```